# How to Start react application in production mode or in nginx server

Tags: reactjs

I have created the production build using

```
npm run build
```

After creating of successful build I have run the command

```
serve -s build
```

how can i start my application on production server in detach mode or in background mode. It is working in my local fine.

Comment: `serve -s build` will serve by default on 5000 port number. You can access this react app by using your sever `ip address:5000` or you can specify port nuber using `-l`

Comment: Yes its working in local if i close the terminal it will stop so what i should do for starting in my production server

Comment: So basically you mean to say you want to run that `cmd` or `terminal` in background. There is no problem with taking reactjs app to production

Comment: Check [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to start the react application or build of application on nginx server
We’ll need to install node to get working with our React app. The following will do the job to get the latest version of Node at the time of running.

```
sudo apt-get update
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

This installs Node, npm, and the build tools that come in handy for npm.

Once Node & npm are installed, we’re going to need to install two tools:

Clone your repository on your machine

```
sudo mkdir /var/www
cd /var/www/
```

Take the clone  or paste the code in the current directory, then change the directory.

```
cd sample-app
```

Install the project on the system.

```
sudo npm install
```

The You need to create the optimized production build of the project

```
sudo npm run build
```

Install and Configure Nginx to serve your application

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and paste the below code

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/sample-app/build;
  server_name localhost;
  index index.html index.htm;
  error_page 404 /;
  location / {
  }
}
```

Now you need to start your server

```
sudo service nginx start
```